# Androind 2.2 Preview 1 - Using ConstraintsLayout with GuideLine app crashes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-studio-2.2, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to create layout using ContraintsLayout.

In my layout I have added horizontal `GuideLine`.

But when I run the app it crashes and if I remove the `GuideLine` it works.

I also checked the APK and there is a class `java.awt.Rectagle`

**StackStrace**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/Rectangle;
 at android.support.constraint.solver.widgets.Guideline.<init>(Guideline.java:43)
 at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.setChildrenConstraints(ConstraintLayout.java:128)
 at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.updateHierarchy(ConstraintLayout.java:106)
 at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onFinishInflate(ConstraintLayout.java:87)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:867)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
 at com.infostretch.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6669)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2578)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2686)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1440)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5969)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:801)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:691)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.awt.Rectangle" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.infostretch.app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.infostretch.app-1/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
 at android.support.constraint.solver.widgets.Guideline.<init>(Guideline.java:43) 
 at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.setChildrenConstraints(ConstraintLayout.java:128) 
 at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.updateHierarchy(ConstraintLayout.java:106) 
 at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onFinishInflate(ConstraintLayout.java:87) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:867) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
 at com.infostretch.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11) 
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6669) 
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2578) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2686) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1440) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5969) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:801) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:691)
```

**Layout xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="80dp">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:src="@color/accent_material_light"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="0"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="0"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="0"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="0"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="0"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="80dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="28dp"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:src="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView11"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="0"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="0"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="367dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="40dp" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:orientation="horizontal"
    app:relativeBegin="83dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="83dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="0"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="0"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="0"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="99dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="MapView"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="230dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="0"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="0"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="0"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="227dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Alert View"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="358dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout3"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="0"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="0"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="0"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="0"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="355dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Recycler View"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="522dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="0"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="0"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="0"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="554dp">

  </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: 1. did you see the "Preview 1" in the name of this version of Android Studio? 2. if so, then better place to post such problem would be https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

Comment: @Blackbelt - I have added GuideLine view in xml file not in java file. So there is no need to import it.

Comment: @MohitSoni Have you added this Dependencies `compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha1'
` in case if you haven't add this.

Comment: @jaydroider - Yes already added

Comment: Can you share the faulty xml file

Comment: @TimCastelijns - xml file added

Comment: Stupid bug one our end, already fixed internally :)

Answer (score 6):

Update:
This issue is fixed in Android Studio 2.2 preview 2 (download from [this page](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/2-2-preview-2)).

> Fixed guidelines crash on device

From the [changelog](http://tools.android.com/recent).

Note that you will have to change `app:orientation` to `android:orientation`

> Changed orientation attribute namespace from app to android to fix a conflict with GridLayout

(also mentioned in changelog).

---

The problem is that the Guideline class internally uses `java.awt.Rectangle`, and `java.awt` libraries are not available for android (apart from the [java.awt.font](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/awt/font/package-summary.html) class).

You cannot edit the Guideline class manually, and you shouldn't want to. The best thing for now is to report the issue at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues like Selvin said, and wait for a fix. In the meantime you cannot use the Guideline class.

Fortunately Guideline is more a convenience class so you should be able to live without it for now. If you really need something like this then you could temporarily use a regular View element that is `0dp` thick and hook up constraints to that.

Comment: We did fix the issue the same day. Sorry this slipped through code reviews. The next public update will have this issue fixed.

Comment: @RomainGuy - Thanks :)

Comment: @RomainGuy thanks. I also noticed that the orientation attribute namespace changed. Included both changes in answer

Comment: Using Studio 2.2 Preview 2 I still had the problem.  The solution for me was to update build.gradle to reference 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha2' rather than '...alpha1'

Comment: @cren I made a new project in preview 2, it probably automatically updated to alpha2

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue... but then I discovered I was using androidX but mistakenly put

```html
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="406dp" />
```

instead of using the androidX equivalent

```html
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="406dp" />
```

I hope this helps someone out there